# Webkit browsers: position:fixed element not behaving as expected

Tags: css, webkit, position, fixed

Here is a code example I've thrown together: http://codepen.io/Nuwen/pen/LHubs

The .fixed div should fadeIn/Out on scroll, controlled by jQuery. This is working correctly in Firefox, but not Chrome or other webkit browsers.

On the advice of other posts, I've added the following properties to .fixed but this hasn't resolved the issue:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Another element is treated with the same bug fixes: #cd-lateral-nav, and it's behaving more or less as expected (besides a small bottom gap in Webkit browsers). I've commented out all transform() properties from all elements [as directed here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574), but that also hasn't changed the outcome. For context, transform() is a Bourbon/Sass mixin that supplies vendor prefixes on a transformation value.

Any ideas why this element isn't accepting position: fixed in Webkit while following the above workarounds?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Very few people have to patience to follow a link and wade through a bunch of code.  Could you trim this down to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome & directional links. I'll strip it down and update my first post now.

Comment: I've removed everything not directly related to this issue.

Comment: I’m guessing you don’t have much control over the page, but you do control everything in the frame.  If that’s the case: (1) You link to three stylesheet and have ~140 lines in an inline stylesheet.  (2) You link to four javascript files, and have ~40 lines in three separate inline tags.  Based on your question, you only need about 10 lines of each in inline tags, and only jQuery externally.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're viewing the full page source. You can directly edit that pen (much like JS fiddle) here: http://codepen.io/Nuwen/pen/LHubs or by clicking "edit this pen" at the bottom of any codepen full/details page.

Comment: The latest version seems to work as you want (although the fading is quick - you may want 2000 instead of 200).  But because your original code was so much, no one is able to tell whether you’ve solved the problem (or even had one in the first place).  Trim everything down to the minimum amount needed to reproduce the problem, or (I predict) you won’t get any help.  And then post here the entire 10 lines needed so that anyone can reproduce the problem, so that anyone coming to this question a month from now can see why things went wrong.

Comment: That's incorrect. I just added extra copy to .ipsum to exaggerate the effect - in Chrome (and other Webkit browsers), the .fixed div appears at bottom: 0 / left: 0 relative to the entire DOM window. I would like it to remain fixed at 0-0 relative to the viewport, so it scrolls along with the page. 

The problem is still present, and it isn't resolved by any of the suggested workarounds for position: fixed & Webkit browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue, after reading through Webkit bugs.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110478

I had commented out transition/transform effects on .fixed **but not parent elements**. This webkit bug will break fixed positioning on ALL descendants (not just when transition/transform are  applied to that element).

The .fixed element can simply be un-nested to exhibit correct behavior, seen here:

http://sandbox.leighjohnson.me/brag-sheet/

Comment: Seems you missed it, but I did post pretty much the same answer around 15 minutes earlier :) Glad you found the solution, though.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, even though it works, we're taking the element away from its transitioned parent.. so we now have to duplicate all that transitioning CSS (as well as any keyframes) on the fixed element that is no longer a child. There's probably a performance hit to this to the duplicate transitioning as well..

Answer (score 0):

I tried editing the CSS in your codepen link, removing stuff with trial and error and I think I finally found the line that is causing the issue.
In the .cd-main-content class, remove the following line:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

For future reference: the above line is usually, as you found out, used on the *fixed* elements to fix certain Chrome bugs (for example when you have a fullscreen video background with negative z-index, a bug I found out about not too long ago). I don't believe it is necessary to put it on a parent element though.